# How to use Two Datasets in Crystal Report without grouping

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which contains two different Datasets. I build the report by Crystal Report Wizard and select two different Datasets as Datasource. Each dataset has a Stored Procedure which returns some columns. I am trying to show the report having all the columns returned from both the reports. But the report shows me the result with grouping. It cross joins the result of both the stored procs. I want to show these independently without any join.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use subreport for second dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the feature you're looking for is subreports.

Put one of your datasets into the main report, then create a subreport and put your second dataset there.

Depending on how you want your report to look, you'll want to experiment with 'on demand subreport' property of the subreport, as well as 'section underlay' property of sections (which will let you layout your subreport side by side with your main report data).

Alternatively, you could create two subreports and put one dataset in each, leaving your main report just as the host for the two subreports.